# UIDate Picker wheel is not showing the list of the day, month and year.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 300, 280);
self.datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
```

UIDate picker wheel is only showing single line day, month and year .. i don't see the the scrolling months.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in iOS 9.0 with a `UIDatePicker` using `UIDatePickerModeDate`.

This is bug in iOS 9 and the hack is to change the `UIDatePicker` mode right before it is displayed, and then change it back to the desired one. Put it in your `viewWillAppear` section.

```
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
```

This has something to do with San francisco font. How wonderful is that?

Comment: No. it is not working  even after i implement the code in the viewWillAppear.